# How can I display the database connection information in the about screen?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an application that allows the user to select a server and database to connect to.  For example they might connect to a QA or a Production instance. Or they might be configured to connect to a SQLLite database vs a MS SQL.

How can I have this information return to the about screen to be displayed so that I can tell what system\database version I am troubleshooting?  So far I have nothing because it is important it read the actual database and not just the connection string because I also want it to have to read a version table in the database and pass the version stored there. The connection information isn't stored in the data so I don't know how to access that information.

Comment: You kinda answered your own question there. Query the version table (and whatever other info you need), parse it as needed and then display it.

Comment: I am kind of new to programming so forgive me if this sounds stupid but how does that get me the connection information?  I can get the information from the version table but if I am just using the connection string stored in the app how will I show the database information?

Comment: Especially if the connection string is encrpyted or something.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ok... So part of your information is in the connection string, part of it is in the database. I haven't downvoted your question, but I'm assuming the ones who did it did so because they were as confused as I am about your question. You should edit it to include every relevant detail, and to make it more clear.

Comment: Edited to include the information that the connection string is part of the information that I am trying to determine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the db name, version, and any other info in the version table. Once you query the version table, the result will have information about your db.\

Comment: Ok, I suppose that would work if I create something to populate those values during the database create process and no body ever moves a database.  I was hoping there was something a bit more dynamic that I could do.